# Recreating large-scale graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

So, I want to recreate a graph of the dielectric dispersion regime.

[image: what I want]

It looks something like that. I'm not sure how best to do it, so right now I'm typing it up by coordinates and using `[smooth]`, which so far has produced:

[image: my attempt]

Surely, there's got to be a better way than painstakingly modifying coordinates?

CODE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{Pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},smooth\\%
}


\begin{axis}[
    align = center, 
    scale only axis,
    separate axis lines,
    xmajorgrids,
    xminorgrids,    
    ymajorgrids,
    every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
    every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    width=4.396in,
    ymode = log,
    xmode=log,
     height=3.257in,
     ymin = 1,
     ymax = 1e8,
     xmin=1e-2,
     xmax = 1e16,
    cycle list name=my black white,
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel={$\varepsilon_r$},
]
% beginning of real curve
\addplot table {
1e0 15e7
4e1 6e7
1.7e2 1.5e5
};
% imaginary peak 1
\addplot table {
1e-2 1
6e-2 1.3
4e-1 2e3
9e-1 6e3
1.7 2e3 
1e1 1.3 
6e1 1 
};
% imaginary peak 2
\addplot table {
1e4 1
6e4 1.3
4e5 2e2
8.5e5 6e2
1.7e6 2e2
1e7 1.3 
6e7 1 
};
% imaginary peak 3
\addplot table {
1e10 1
6e10 1.3
2.5e11 2e1
8e11 4e1
2.7e12 2e1
1e13 1.3 
6e13 1 
};
% imaginary peak 4, not yet worked on
%\addplot table {
%1e13 1
%6e13 1.3
%4e14 2e3
%9e14 6e3
%3e15 2e3 
%1e16 1.3 
%6e16 1 
%};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This shouldn't take too long... 
[image]

---

So, after thinking of possible solutions, I decided to use an online tool called WebPlotDigitizer, which takes some X-Y graph, maps the axes and then digitises the plot data in accordance with those axes... And I just kept my data for the bumps...

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code of what you have so far as well?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Code added

Comment: Unless you have the data underlying the original plot, I don't think there's an alternative to manually adding the coordinates.  By looking at the plot, I'd say around 30-40 points.

Comment: @ElmarPeise that's what I though. That kind of plot, unfortunately, has no data associated with it, it's completely idealised and most probably sketched.

Comment: Maybe it would be convenient to write a tikz path using the sin / cos operations as in [section 9.11 here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse9.html)

Comment: I was going to suggest using WebPlotDigitizer. Now all that you need to do is to add nodes to your graph with the proper labels. uses $(axis cs: x, y)$.

Comment: @ZanCoul I wish you had, you could have saved me some time scratching my head! That's right, it's coming along...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer was apparently to use a web service, as noted in an answer in the question and in the comments.